# How is typeid implemented?

Tags: c++, types, typeid

I've read that it is implementation specific depending on your compiler, but what might be one way it is implemented? I am asking mainly because I want to know how it creates a name for a type. I'm relatively knew to programming and to C++ but what I've seen so far, it doesn't seem possible to turn a type into a string before runtime.
I was thinking the name generation could be done with macros and token-pasting sort of like this:

```
#define Put_In_Quotes(input) #input

template<class T>
const char* type_name(T data_type){
   return Put_In_Quotes(T); 
}
```

But I think this would simply return the literal string "T" instead of the type name. Not to mention it doesn't explain how typeid lets you enter just types and not values for its datatype parameter, eg. `typeid(int).name()`
All answers or guides to more information are greatly appreciated

Comment: Keep in mind that `typeid` is an operator, not a function... it's  hard-coded into the compiler, not just part of a code library somewhere, so it can do things that "normal functions" cannot, like accept a typename as an argument rather than a value.   (compare its capabilities with the more commonly used `sizeof` operator, for example)

Comment: *"what I've seen so far, it doesn't seem possible to turn a type into a string before runtime."* -- hence the need for `typeid`. ;)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner yea that’s another thing I’ve been told but the C++ compiler was coded in C++ right? Doesn’t that mean there’s something native to C++ that lets you implement typeid?

Comment: Just think of it as a virtual function that the compiler adds invisibly to the class.

Comment: @TheCuriousCoder "*the C++ compiler was coded in C++ right?*" - modern C++ compilers can be, yes (ie, "dogfooding"), but what do you think early C++ compilers were written in before C++ existed? "*Doesn’t that mean there’s something native to C++ that lets you implement typeid?*" - no. The compiler is just parsing your source code and outputting binary code for the linker to then consume. Whatever logic the compiler uses to produce that binary code (like typeid) is private to the compiler. Thinking back to the early compilers, `typeid` still had to be implemented, but without any help from C++

Comment: @TheCuriousCoder the compiler (regardless of which language it is written in), simply by dint of being the compiler, has access to lots of private capabilities that the "normal" C++ code it is compiling does not.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SE!

The compiler knows all the possible types your program might employ just like it knows which template forms your program needs instantiated. (As for the particular name strings it generates, different compilers use all sorts of conventions for how they name things internally.)

In simple terms, the `typeid` operator just returns a `type_info` object, right? Broadly speaking, that object is essentially all there is to implementing a type's RTTI: a `type_info` kept in the vtable, which is returned by `typeid`.

You mentioned you were new to C++, but if you look up how to do a vtable dump for your compiler, you can examine the actual data yourself. The formatting specifics of every compiler will differ, of course, but for a polymorphic type, you'll usually find this info right alongside the rest of that type's vtable data. Depending on how your compiler formats that output, it may look something like an additional struct member of that type and may (usually?) immediately precede or follow the rest of the type data. Static types will have similar data residing elsewhere.